# Changing caption label font not working

Tags: formatting, captions

I've been trying to change the format of caption labels for figures, following the [documentation](https://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf). However, I can't seem to make it not be in small caps, despite multiple attempts. The package seems to otherwise work normally, as setting the "fontlabel" option to "bf" gives me a bolded result (but still in small caps). The following minimal-working example:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section*{Bibliographie}}
\usepackage[labelfont=up]{caption}
\usepackage[]{subcaption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.93\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=1.00\textwidth]{pictures/oFrolicheZeit.png}
            \caption{\textit{Wacht\string! Euch zum Streit gefasset macht}, acte III, \enquote{O fröliche Zeit}, mes. 8-12.}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.93\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=1.00\textwidth]{pictures/ichKannNichtMehr.png}
            \caption{\textit{Wacht\string! Euch zum Streit gefasset macht}, acte III, \enquote{Ich kann nicht mehr}, mes. 6-13.}
        \end{subfigure} 
        \caption[]{Insert musical analysis caption here.}
        \label{fig:rhetoric}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Gives the below output once compiled to a pdf:

[image: Example]

I don't know if this might be caused by some conflict between the caption and subcaption packages or if I'm missing something. Cheers,

Comment: Edit: there is a [entirely non-obvious] workaround (found by sheer dumb luck), which is manually setting: \usepackage[figurename=Figure]{caption} - somehow, this gets "Figure" into normal font instead of it being stuck into small caps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're being bitten by `babel-french`. Use

```
\frenchsetup{SmallCapsFigTabCaptions=false}
```

Note that the manual has `SmallCapsFigTabcaptions`, but it's wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[labelfont=up]{caption}
\usepackage[]{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\frenchsetup{SmallCapsFigTabCaptions=false}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{0.93\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{\textit{Wacht\string! Euch zum Streit gefasset macht}, acte III, 
  \enquote{O fröliche Zeit}, mes. 8-12.}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.93\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{\textit{Wacht\string! Euch zum Streit gefasset macht}, acte III,
  \enquote{Ich kann nicht mehr}, mes. 6-13.}
\end{subfigure} 

\caption{Insert musical analysis caption here.}\label{fig:rhetoric}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This solution seems more intuitive and makes for more immediately understandable code than the sneaky workaround I ultimately figured.

Answer (score 4):

Use `\captionsetup` to set caption format for figures and subfigures independently.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section*{Bibliographie}}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{textfont={normalsize,sc}}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\captionsetup[subfigure]{textfont={normalsize}}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage[]{subcaption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.6\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=1.00\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{\textit{Wacht\string! Euch zum Streit gefasset macht}, acte III, {O fröliche Zeit}, mes. 8-12.}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.6\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=1.00\textwidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{\textit{Wacht\string! Euch zum Streit gefasset macht}, acte III, {Ich kann nicht mehr}, mes. 6-13.}
        \end{subfigure} 
        \caption{Insert musical analysis caption here.}
        \label{fig:rhetoric}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've tried this, and with other options too, but it does not seem to solve my base problem, which is that "Figure" remains in small caps [although I just now appear to have found a workaround for that] (changing the font family, for example, seems to only affect the number and not the "Figure" part).

Comment: @AlexJ This is the default. Use `labelfont=`  to change it.

Comment: The example I provided specifically set "labelfont=up" [and I also tried with "labelfont=normalfont"] ("up", per the documentation, is supposed to provide normal, "upright", non-italic, non-bolded, non-small caps, text. Seemingly, setting "labelfont=up" does not override the default small caps (although redefining what "figurename" is seems to do the trick, albeit in a non-obvious way).